# I want suggestions in the command line in Neovim - NvChad

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1qu.png)

I want suggestions in the command, like shown in the screenshot. When i am typing ":term" it is not showing suggestions.
I am using the base NvChad configuration on my windows system. [github](https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad)
FYI I am new to neovim/vim, so I might not know the basic terminologies. Before this config, i used a different one which had suggestions for commands. it used to show multiple options for the words.

i am expecting suggestion for commands.

Answer (score 1):

[wilder.nvim](https://github.com/gelguy/wilder.nvim) may be what you're looking for. As you type it'll give you lsp-style suggestions. A preview, as well as installation instructions are on the GitHub page. I believe NvChad uses packer, so use that installation.